# format subtract dates result to "hh:mm:ss"

Tags: visual-studio, date, subtraction

I need to format subtract 2 long date time result to "hh.mm.ss"

```
open date           closed date           subtracted
01/01/2012 16:04    04/01/2012 17:07      3.01:02:58
02/01/2012 08:52    02/01/2012 17:03        08:10:27
```

using

```
closeddate.subtract(opendate)
```

return result in format `D.hh:mm:ss`

and using

```
DateDiff("h", OpenDate, closeDate)
```

return hours only (no minutes or seconds)

Also tried

```
closeddate.subtract(opendate).tostring("hh:mm:ss")
```

not working

Comment: Please confirm what version of VB you're using: VB6 or VB.NET?

Comment: vb.net (visual studio 2013)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as  many Microsoft forums answered there is no way to do that

so i used

```
DateDiff("s", OpenDate, closeDate)
```

and passed result to helper function return calculated time in format hh:mm:ss